# How do you write regular expressions for a valid username for swift?

Tags: ios, swift, regex

Here are some requirements for being a valid username:

1. No special characteristics
2. Allow underscore
3. No spaces
4. Letter and numbers between 1-13 characters

Comment: Please include your own efforts in your questions i.e. your attempts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^\w{1,13}$
```

**^** beginning of string anchor

**\w** word character - any letter (including UTF-8), any case, 0-9 and underscore

**{1,13}** length between 1 and 13, inclusive

**$** end of string anchor

https://regex101.com/ - good resource

Comment: Don't use the slash delimiter in the Swift regex flavor

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9](_|)[a-zA-Z0-9])*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

Comment: Don't use the slash delimiter in the Swift regex flavor

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,13}$
```

**[a-zA-Z0-9_]** Allows only small a to z, capital A to Z, 0 to 9 number with _ underscore

**{1,13}** Allow string length between 1 to 10 Letter and numbers

Answer (score 0):

RegEx Start with char `^` and End with `$` between them is rules

`[a-z0-9_-]`  rule for characters (a-z) and numbers (0-9) + underscore, hyphen
   `{1,13}`   rule for Length at least 1 characters and maximum length of 13

**String Extention:**

```
 extension String {
        var isValidUserName : Bool {
            let userNameRegEx = "^[a-z0-9_-]{1,13}$"

            let userNameChecker = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES[c] %@", userNameRegEx)
            return userNameChecker.evaluate(with: self)
        }
    }
```

**Result:**

```
print("userName_1".isValidUserName) //True
print("user name".isValidUserName) //False  Space
print("username123248632".isValidUserName) //False  size
print("uerName#$1".isValidUserName) //False  Special characteristics
print("uerName`d".isValidUserName) //False  Special characteristics
```

Comment: Instead of using an NSPredicate, you can do: `return self.compare(userNameRegEx, options: .regularExpression) == .orderedSame`

Comment: @rmaddy i test it return false in first check

Comment: Try `return self.range(of: userNameRegEx, options: .regularExpression) != nil`. I forgot that the `.regularExpression` option can't be used with `compare`.

Comment: @rmaddy not work , but this work   `guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: userNameRegEx, options: .caseInsensitive) else { return false }
        return regex.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.count)).count != 0`

Comment: Actually, my second suggestion works just fine when the correct regular expression is used. It needs to be `"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,13}$"`. This allows letter, numbers, and underscores.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Objective-C**

```
- (BOOL)checkValidation:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSString *rejex = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,13}$";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", rejex];

    //if rejex fullfil than it will return true else false.
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:textField.text];
}
```

**Swift**

```
 func checkValidation(testStr:String) -> Bool {        
    let emailRegEx = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,13}$"

    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    return emailTest.evaluate(with: testStr)
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged Swift, not Objective-C. Please post answers in the correct language.